# Cannot interact between react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is for a react JS project ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y71r5r6b/16/)). The textbox should update with the true/false checked value of the checkbox, but it does not do so. Can someone explain why?

```
var AutoGenerateCheckbox = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {checked: false};
  },
  update() {
    this.state.checked = !this.state.checked;
    alert(this.state.checked);
    this.props.onUpdate(this.state.checked);
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.update} />
    );
  }
});

var TBox = React.createClass({displayName: 'TextBox',
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        Checkbox value: {this.props.data}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var KApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {autoChecked: false};
  },
  handleAutogenChange: function(val) {
    alert('handleAutogenChange:' + val);
    this.setState({autoChecked : val});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
        <AutoGenerateCheckbox onUpdate={this.handleAutogenChange}/>
        <TBox data={this.state.autoChecked}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <KApp />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: `this.state.checked = !this.state.checked` Why are you modifying state directly without using `setState()`?

Comment: @lux Because I just started learning react and I have no idea what I'm doing. Thanks for the tip, I will look into setState.

Comment: Ah cool, was confused since you were utilizing `setState` in another component, so just wanted to ensure I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you don't see anything printed out is because you are trying to print a `boolean` value here

```
<div>
    Checkbox value: {this.props.data}
</div>
```

try

```
<div>
    Checkbox value: {this.props.data.toString()}
</div>
```

instead.

As an extra tip, you don't really need to hold the state of the checkbox in both its own state and its parent component's state. You really only need to have it in the parent component's state.

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkarajohn/y71r5r6b/17/) I made.

Comment: Awesome thank you for the tip. Logically, I would think the checkbox controls its own value... is the way I designed it (with the parent managing the interaction between checkbox and textbox) the best way? Is there any other 'best practice' to do it? I keep reading about refs and whatnot and am a little overwhelming.

Comment: Does the checkbox really control its own value? Or is the checkbox simply a switch for changing the state of your app (the `KApp` component), which is then propagated down to its children components? :) About the "best way" part, what you did here is pretty much how the state should flow from parent to children. Figuring out where the state should live is a part of thinking in the "react way"

Comment: Also I want to point out that there is really no interaction between the checkbox and the textbox, meaning that they don't know about each other's existence and they don't care about each other's existence. All they care about is what props you pass down to them, so that they can render based on them.

Comment: Regarding refs, that's React's way to allow you to get a reference to the actual DOM node that is put into the page, in case you need to interact with it in some way that React event handlers are not enough (for example passing it to JQuery)

Comment: Thanks so much Mitch, all of that makes sense. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

React is not determining the Boolean value to be printable information, try this instead:

```
<div>
    Checkbox value: {this.props.data.toString()}
</div>
```